# QQmlComponent: Component is not ready

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, qml

I'm following through the [Create a currency converter app](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/app-developer-cookbook/mobile/currency-converter-phone-app/) tutorial. I'm on a fresh raring install and have installed the ubuntu-sdk. I created a new project (QT Quick 2 UI) and copied in the CurrencyConverter.qml text. But when I use Ctrl-R to run qmlscene I get the error 'QQmlComponent: Component is not ready', qmlscene seems to run fine but the Currency Converter title text is missing.

[image]

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is already a bug assigned.

See here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-ui-toolkit/+bug/1158246

The ui toolkit is still under heavy development, the bug is confirmed and assigned to the tutorials author David Planella.

Comment: Great, thanks for the reply, the bug report has some new code and it's now working.